# How do I make CALayers use center of screen as vanishing point when doing 3D transformations?

Tags: ios, 3d, core-animation

I have a 2D grid of views (I'll call them tiles) on the screen. Each tile has a subview which I am rotating around the Y axis in an animation block. I have set sublayerTransform properly on each tile. All the subviews which I am rotating do exhibit 3D perspective. The problem is the vanishing point for each one is the center of the tile instead of the center of the screen, disrupting the illusion of 3D. When I set sublayerTransform on the parent of all the tiles, the rotating views do not exhibit any perspective. I believe this is because sublayerTransform only applies to the children of a layer and not too grandchildren. How do I make all rotating views use the same vanishing point? I've included a poorly drawn image to help illustrate the point. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution: you have to add translation transform to superlayer then make up for it by adjusting sublayer's position. I've used a following piece of code successfully, just create an empty "Single View Application" XCode project and run in on the iPad simulator:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        CALayer *parent = [CALayer layer];
        parent.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        parent.position = CGPointMake(70 + 120*i, 70);
        parent.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:parent];

        float width = self.view.frame.size.width/2.0;
        float offset = (width - parent.position.x);

        CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
        layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
        layer.position = CGPointMake(-offset + 50, 60);
        layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0);

        CATransform3D tr = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(offset, 0, 0);
        CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity ;
        t.m34 = -4.0f/2000.0f ;
        parent.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DConcat(t, tr);

        [parent addSublayer:layer];    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly complex problem to solve. I suggest you look and see how others have solved it. Take a look at [iCarousel from Nick Lockwood](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). It's a carousel implementation that might give you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `sublayerTransform` on the parent of the tiles, but using  [`CATransformLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransformLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) for the tiles? This should propagate the `sublayerTransform` further down your hierarchy. Note that `CATransformLayer` only renders its sublayers, rather than any content/background colors of its own, so anything you were doing in the tile itself may need to be moved into a separate sublayer.

Answer (score 0):

Try rotating the tiles themselves instead of their subviews. On your superview of your tile views, set your perspective transform:

```
CATransform3D t = kCATransform3DIdentity ;
t.m34 = -1.0f/2000.0f ;
parentLayer.sublayerTransform = t ;
```

Would that work? Although I assume you explicitly don't want to rotate the tiles themselves?